# HTA VBScript: dynamically create function at runtime from a string or variable that contains a string as in JavaScript with new Function() constructor

Tags: function, vbscript, hta

I am trying to learn a bit more of [HTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application) and [VBScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) and I want to know if VBS allows to create dynamically functions as in JavaScript as:

```
var f = new Function('functionName', functionbody);
```

or

```
window['functionName'] = function() { functionbody };
```

Into the HTA, there is a <textarea> in witch the user writes its code as a string and I want to dynamically transform it into a VBScript function at runtime.

In other words, is there an equivalent of the **new Function() constructor** in HTA/VBScript that is available in JavaScript and of course without mixing JavaScript code with VBScript code into the same HTA file?

Comment: Be aware that HTA is strongly deprecated and the capability may be removed from Windows at any time. Microsoft is promoting [Progressive Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps-chromium/) instead, and both Chrome and Edge have the capability of "installing" websites as "apps".

Comment: @JeffZeitlin not with VBScript though it should be mentioned.

Comment: Why not write the the HTA with JScript instead of VBScript?

Comment: @LesFerch I suppose because one has features that the other doesn't have and viceversa, but I don't know exactly because I am just learning a bit of both and trying to understand witch one is the best choice to use case by case. And usually I use js for html and vbs for hta because hta is run by mshta.exe that refers to ie engine and afaik it is not very good at running standard and up to date js as ES6. But I am not sure if such a way is the best possible and maybe it isn't: Just trying to learn by trial and mistake approach.

Comment: @user692942 I am not sure: I mean that **in part** it answers my question, but since the main thing is if there is a **new Function() constructor** (or kind of) in vbs too as in js and since your comment gives just a partial answer I have to suppose it doesn't exist such a thing in vbs. After all eval() and Execute in vbs are not like **new Function** constructor in js that seems by far more powerful by far. But I am still trying to understand very well both comparing them and learning about them. So I tend to remain open to further ideas.

Comment: JScript is not modern JavaScript, but it's usually a better choice than VBScript in HTAs due to a few additional features and because it's less likely to have been uninstalled or disabled on any given machine. Here's the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/d1et7k7c(v=vs.84)).